# ColumnChart move month to x axis considering provided JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

ORIGINAL POST:

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate how my data comes from JSON and renders in a ColumnChart.

https://jsfiddle.net/w4dokdt9/3/

My JSON comes over like this:

```
[{"lPlusScoreID":1,"jan":60.03,"feb":43.57,"mar":48.55},
 {"lPlusScoreID":2, "jan":89.42,"feb":85.71,"mar":90.46},
 {"lPlusScoreID":3,"jan":86.22,"feb":90.61,"mar":89.53}]
```

The column chart comes out like this:
[image]

My goal is month across the x-axis and product as column/bar.

How can I accomplish this?  I prefer a Google Visualization chart, method, or configuration option.

Coding to transform the data would be OK if that is the only way, but I new to developing.

Thank you so much, as always!

**EDITED POST:**

I finally used the below code.

1. Created `dataArray_input` with hard coded months and then filled it
   with data from original JSON.
2. Transposed `dataArray_input` using `transposeArray()` function into
   `dataArray_trans`.

   ```
   function transposeArray(a) {
   return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) {
       return a.map(function (r) {
           return r[c];
       });
   });  }
   ```
3. Append `dataArray_trans` using `appendArray()` function to final `dataArray_output` which then is used by the Google API

   ```
   function appendArray(a, b) {
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       b.push(a[i]);
   }    }
   ```

Below is the final code.

I would welcome some feedback to make sure I'm learning in the proper way and direction.  New to this stuff.

Thank you also to @WhiteHat for answering so quickly, also with a good solution.

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChartXYZ();
};


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  Remove Duplicates in singleDimensionalArray
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  Transpose Array
/*  Source1:  https://jsfiddle.net/w4dokdt9/6/
    Source2:  http://geniuscarrier.com/transpose-in-javascript/
    Call:     a = array to transpose
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function transposeArray(a) {
    return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) {
        return a.map(function (r) {
            return r[c];
        });
    });
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  Append Array
/*  Source1:  https://davidwalsh.name/combining-js-arrays
    Call:     a = source, b = destination   "a onto b"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function appendArray(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b.push(a[i]);
    }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  Google Function
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function drawChartXYZ() {

    //var urlString = '../mps/forecastVols' + urlParameter1 + urlParameter1_Value;
    //var urlString_temp = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    var urlString_temp = 'https://httpbin.org/get';     //source: https://resttesttest.com/

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        //url: urlString,
        url: urlString_temp,
        success: function (result) {

            //Manually loaded "result" with JSON that normally comes from "urlString".   
            result = [{"name":"Sensor","techName":"GS_SI","p1":305901.00,"p2":343653.00,"p3":414684.00,"p4":324323.00,"p5":366401.00,"p6":369596.00,"p7":273567.00,"p8":407767.00,"p9":396620.00,"p10":434000.00,"p11":392000.00,"p12":336000.00,"p13":420000.00,"p14":378000.00,"p15":434000.00,"p16":420000.00,"p17":420000.00,"p18":434000.00,"p19":336000.00,"p20":434000.00,"p21":406000.00,"p22":0.00,"p23":0.00,"p24":0.00,"p25":358884.00,"p26":335730.00,"p27":358884.00,"p28":347307.00,"p29":358884.00,"p30":347307.00,"p31":361409.00,"p32":361409.00,"p33":349751.00,"p34":361409.00,"p35":349751.00,"p36":361409.00,"p37":0.00,"p38":0.00,"p39":0.00,"p40":0.00,"p41":0.00,"p42":0.00,"p43":0.00,"p44":0.00,"p45":0.00,"p46":0.00,"p47":0.00,"p48":0.00,"id":2,"b1":null,"b2":null}];   
   
            //Declare Array Variables
            var dataArray_ID = [];          //ID List
            var dataArray_input = [];       //Input
            var dataArary_trans = [];       //Transpose 
            var dataArray_output = [];      //Output

            //Unique product ID's from JSON result
            $.each(result, function (j, obj) {
                dataArray_ID.push([
                    obj.id
                ]);
            });
            dataArray_ID.filter(onlyUnique);

            //Loop for each ID:  Input, Transpose, Output
            for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_ID.length; ++j) {

                dataArray_input = [];
                dataArray_input.push([
                    'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
                ]);

                //Input Array
                $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                    if (obj.id == dataArray_ID[j]) {
                        dataArray_input.push([
                           //"Line ID",
                           obj.id,
                           obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, 
                           obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, obj.id, obj.id
                        ]);
                        dataArray_input.push([
                           //"Prod CY",
                           obj.p1, //JAN_CY
                           obj.p2, obj.p3, obj.p4, obj.p5, obj.p6, obj.p7, 
                           obj.p8, obj.p9, obj.p10, obj.p11, obj.p12
                        ]);
                        dataArray_input.push([
                           //"BP CY",
                           obj.p25, //JAN_CY_BP
                           obj.p26, obj.p27, obj.p28, obj.p29, obj.p30, obj.p31, 
                           obj.p32, obj.p33, obj.p34, obj.p35, obj.p36
                        ]);
                        dataArray_input.push([
                           //"Prod CY+1",
                           obj.p13, //JAN_CYPLUS1
                           obj.p14, obj.p15, obj.p16, obj.p17, obj.p18, obj.p19, 
                           obj.p20, obj.p21, obj.p22, obj.p23, obj.p24
                        ]);
                        dataArray_input.push([
                           //"BP CY+1",
                           obj.p37, //JAN_CYPLUS1_BP
                           obj.p38, obj.p39, obj.p40, obj.p41, obj.p42, obj.p43, 
                           obj.p44, obj.p45, obj.p46, obj.p47, obj.p48
                        ]);
                    } //END if
                }); //END $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            }; //END for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_ID.length; ++j) {

            //Transpose Array
            dataArray_trans = transposeArray(dataArray_input);

            //Append Array to Output
            appendArray(dataArray_trans, dataArray_output);

            //Create DataTable
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            //Add Columns
            data.addColumn('string', 'Month');//0
            data.addColumn('number', 'Line ID');//1
            data.addColumn('number', 'Prod CY');//2
            data.addColumn('number', 'BP CY');//3
            data.addColumn('number', 'Prod CY+1');//4
            data.addColumn('number', 'BP CY+1');//5

            data.addRows(dataArray_output);

            //Create Data View
            var viewFilter = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            viewFilter.setColumns([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            viewFilter.setRows(viewFilter.getFilteredRows([{ column: 1, value: 2 }])); 
 
            var viewTable = new google.visualization.DataView(viewFilter);
            viewTable.setColumns([0, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

            var viewChart1 = new google.visualization.DataView(viewFilter);
            viewChart1.setColumns([0, 2, 3]);
  
            //Options
            var optionsTable = {
            };

            var optionsChart1 = {
                title: 'Volume Development - CY',
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Volume',
                    minValue: '0'
                },
                series: {
                    0: { type: 'bars' },    //Prod CY
                    1: { type: 'line' },    //BP CY
                }
            };

            //Instantiate and draw chart, passing in options.
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(viewTable, optionsTable);

            var chart1 = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('div_chart1'));
            chart1.draw(viewChart1, optionsChart1);

        } //END  success: function (result) {
    }); //END  $.ajax({
} //END  function drawChart()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="table_div"></div>
<hr />
<div id="div_chart1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with google charts, it's all in how the data is fed to the chart

there are [data manipulation methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data) for `group()` and `join()`
but not any to pivot from columns to rows, etc...

for the requested chart, the data will need to be structured as follows...

```
['month', 'Product1', 'Product2']
['jan', 60.03, 89.42]
['feb', 43.57, 85.71]
```

see following working snippet...

the data table is created with a single column for month
a new column is added for each `"lPlusScoreID"`

data table method `getFilteredRows` is used to see if the month has already been added as row
if so, the row is updated
otherwise, a new row is added

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = [
    {"lPlusScoreID":1, "jan":60.03, "feb":43.57, "mar":48.55},
    {"lPlusScoreID":2, "jan":89.42, "feb":85.71, "mar":90.46},
    {"lPlusScoreID":3, "jan":86.22, "feb":90.61, "mar":89.53}
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Month');

  // build data
  jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
    var colIndex;
    var rowIndex;

    // process each key in the row object
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
      // add column for ID
      if (key === 'lPlusScoreID') {
        colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'Product' + row.lPlusScoreID.toString());
        return;
      }

      // find / add row for month
      rowIndex = getRowIndex(key);
      if (rowIndex === null) {
        rowIndex = data.addRow();
        data.setValue(rowIndex, 0, key);
      }
      data.setValue(rowIndex, colIndex, row[key]);
    });
  });

  function getRowIndex(rowMonth) {
    var rowIndex = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: rowMonth
    }]);
    if (rowIndex.length > 0) {
      return rowIndex[0];
    }
    return null;
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to get back to this topic.  I follow your solution and it makes sense to me.  I ended up running across a script which was shorter and ended up working in my application.  Could you take a look at my edit and let me know what you think?  I normally look advise from pros in the forums for best practices since I'm relatively new to Javascript.

Comment: And thank you for being there to help!  It's hard to find people who know how this stuff works.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for your help!